# Value of input changed to %5Bobject+Object%5D when submit launched (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

So this is the **situation** :

I have multiple choices

[image]

The idea is that when I click on "Reserver" I get the value of the elements and modify an hidden formulaire with this function :

```
 $(".reservationGo").click(function(){
    $("#depCityCode").attr('value',$(this).closest('.productsDispo').find($('.depCityCode_').attr('value')));
    $("#dateDep").val($(this).parents('.productsDispo').find($('.dateDep_').attr('value')));
    $('#nightDuration').attr('value',$(this).closest('.productsDispo').find('.nightDuration_').attr('value'));
    $('#dayDuration').attr('value',$(this).closest('.productsDispo').find('.dayDuration_').attr('value'));

    });

    $('#reservation').submit();
});
```

However instead of returning the value I want, I get in the URL this :

```
Parameters=&depCityCode=%5Bobject+Object%5D&dateDep=%5Bobject+Object%5D...
```

So `%5Bobject+Object%5D`instead of the value I want..

### Clarified HTML

```
<form class="hiddenForm" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" id="depCityCode">
   <input type="hidden" id="dateDep">
   ...
</form>

<div class="productDispo">
   <div class="depCityCode_" value="codeCity">A city</div>
   <div class="dateDep_" value="codeDate">2035-28-08</div>
   ...

</div>
```

### Complete HTML for beter comprehension

```
<form name='reservation' action='http://resa...' method="POST" id="reservation" onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_linkByPost', this]);">

<input type="hidden" id="productLive" name="product" value="{$product.info.code}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="complementaryParameters" value=""/>

<input type="text" name="depCityCode" id="depCityCode" style="display:none"  />
<input type="text" name="dateDep" id="dateDep" style="display:none" />
<input type="text" name="nightDuration" id="nightDuration"  style="display:none" />
<input type="text" name="dayDuration" id="dayDuration"  style="display:none" />
<input type="text" name="provider" value="{$product.tourOperator.code}" style="display:none" />
<input type="text" name="toCode" id="toProduct" value="{$product.info.toProductCode}" style="display:none" />
<input type="text" name="catalogCode" value="{$product.info.code}" style="display:none" />
{{--@if($ecall)
<input type="text" name="reservationProfileChannelCode" value="ECALL" style="display:none" />
@else
<input type="text" name="reservationProfileChannelCode" value="ADV" style="display:none" />
@endif--}}
<input type="text" name="nbAdults" id="nbAdults" style="display:none" />
<input type="text" name="nbChildren" id="nbChildren" style="display:none" />
<input type="text" name="nbBabies" id="nbBabies" style="display:none" />
<input type="text" name="productUrl" id="productUrl" style="display:none" value="http://www.agencedevoyage.com/{$product.slug}_{$product.info.code}.html" />
<input type="text" name="homeUrl" id="homeUrl" style="display:none" value="http://www.agencedevoyage.com" />
<span id="ageChild" style="display:none"></span>

<div class="update-search clearfix">
    <div id="formulaireChoixSejour">
        <h2 style="padding-bottom: 10px">Choisissez le séjour qui vous convient le <span class="nowrap">mieux :<span></h2>
        <div class="changeClass"> <!-- Séparation pour tablette et inf -->
            <div class="col-xs-3 changeSubClass3">
                <label>Ville de départ :</label>
                <div class="selector">
                    <select id="departureCitys">
                        <option></option>
                    </select><span class="custom-select full-width" > <!-- Maël : Valeur a varier pour affichage --> </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 changeSubClass2">
                <label id="bug4">Date de départ :</label>
                <div class="selector">
                    <select id="departureDates">
                        <option></option>
                    </select><span class="custom-select full-width"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="changeClass">
            <div class="col-xs-2 changeSubClass2">
                <label>Durée :</label>
                <div class="selector">
                    <select id="departureDurations">
                        <option></option>
                    </select><span class="custom-select full-width"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 changeSubClass2">
                <label>Formule(s) :</label>
                <div class="selector">
                    <select id="departureMealPlans">
                        <option></option>
                    </select><span class="custom-select full-width"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 changeSubClass2">
                <label id="bug2">Prix TTC<br/>par<br/>personne :</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 changeSubClass1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bug3"></div>
    <div id='errorMessage'>Désolé il n'y a pas de produit correspondant à votre demande.</div>
    @foreach($dispos as $key => $dispo)
        <div class="productsDispo">
            <div class="changeClass">
                <div class="col-xs-3 changeSubClass33 depCityCode_" value="{{$dispo -> City -> code}}">
                    {{$dispo -> City -> name}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 changeSubClass32 dateDep_" value="{{$dispo -> go }}">
                    {{$dispo -> go}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 changeSubClass32 productDuration">
                    <span class="dayDuration_">{{$dispo -> nb_days}}</span>j / <span class="nightDuration_">{{$dispo -> nb_nights}}</span>n
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="changeClass bug6">
                <div class="col-xs-2 changeSubClass32 mealPlan value="{{$dispo -> formula -> slug}}">
                {{$dispo -> formula->name}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 changeSubClass32 priceProd">
                {{$dispo -> price}}€
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 changeSubClass31">
                <button class="reservationGo bug5" a="#">Réserver</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
@endforeach
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    @include('common.function_fullFillForm')
</script>

</div>
```

So have you guys an idea of where this could came from ?

Comment: is this: `.find($('.dateDep_').attr('value'))` intencional? because you'll be running: `find(codeDate)`. also the problem is that your value is an object. of type [object Object] and then when its url encoded you get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace

```
$("#depCityCode").attr('value',$(this).closest('.productsDispo').find($('.depCityCode_').attr('value')));
```

with

```
$("#depCityCode").attr('value', $(this).closest('.productsDispo').find($('.depCityCode_')).attr('value'));
```

Comment: *Explain* what the problem is and show how it can be fixed. "Do this" answers are not very helpful.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen thank you for you note. In this case I think It is obvious, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think , this is the problem of browser cookies , once clear whole browser
   cookies completely from beginning.Then check because some time its taking 
   default string value from browser.